# Is there a way to bind a delegate command to an Image?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, prism, silverlight-5.0

I'm working with Silverlight 5.0. I'm using PRISM as my main framework, and I'd like to bind my delegateCommand to my imagen when the user press click on it.

I was thinking if I need to create de DependencyObject to incrust the property into the control, but it's just an idea what I had. c#

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What???????????  when the user press click on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a Button and set its content to image.